# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.controller('myView')')

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

I'm getting the below error while doing karma/jasmine unit testing for both the test cases.I tried by modifying the controller by adding angular.controller in the spec file even then it is not working.Is there any way to fix?

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.controller('myView')')
```

myView.spec.js

```
// myView.spec.js
(function(){
describe('controller: myView', function(){


     var module,myView,$q, $rootScope, $scope, uiGridConstants, overviewService, commonService, $timeout;
    beforeEach(function() {
        module = angular.module('app.myView');
        controller= angular.controller('myView')
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$q_, _$rootScope_, _$timeout_) {

        $q= _$q_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
         $timeout= _$timeout_;

        myView= $controller('myView', {
            $q : _$q_,
            $rootScope :  _$rootScope_,
             $timeout:  _$timeout_
        });


    }));

    describe("myViewto be defined", function() {
        it("should be created successfully", function () {
            expect(controller).toBeDefined();
        });

        it("overview should be defined", function () {
            expect(myView()).toBeDefined();
        });

    });

});

})();
```

and myView.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.myView')
        .controller('myView', myView);

    function myView($q, $rootScope, $scope, uiGridConstants, myViewService, commonService, $timeout) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.callFeedback = function () { };
})();
```

Comment: What is `myView`? Did you want to use `overview` instead?

Comment: Sorry Typo.It is myView only.I've updated the codes.

Comment: @Hema Nandagopal , if you found my ans useful you can accept it

Answer (score 3):

Sharing following code

```
// myView.spec.js
(function(){
describe('myView', function(){
  var $controller, myView;

   //we use angular-mocks to specify which modules we'll need within this  
   //test file. 
   beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app.myView'));

   // Inject the $controller service to create instances of the controller 
   //(myView) we want to test
   beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
      $controller = _$controller_;
      myView = $controller('myView', {});
    }));

   // Verify our controller exists
   it('should be defined', function() {
      expect(myView).toBeDefined();
   });
  });

})();
```

We set `_$controller_`to the `$controller` variable we created and then create an instance of our controller by calling $controller('myView', {}). The first argument is the name of the controller we want to test and the second argument is an object of the dependencies for our controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the injected parameters to your controller as shown:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.myView')
    .controller($q,$rootScope,$scope,uiGridConstants,'myView', myView);

function myView($q, $rootScope, $scope, uiGridConstants, myViewService, commonService, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.callFeedback = function () { };
```

})();

Also make sure that your module has all the necesary dependences in the `angular.module('app.myView',['uiGridConstants', ...'etc']);`